# replace objects in array from another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I'm trying to replace object(s) in an array from another array while keeping the index/order in place.

So arrayOne:

```
[
    {
        "color": "#f8edd1",
        "selected": true
    },
    {
        "color": "#d88a8a",
        "selected": false
    },
    {
        "color": "#474843",
        "selected": false
    },
    {
        "color": "#9d9d93",
        "selected": true
    },
    {
        "color": "#c5cfc6",
        "selected": false
    }
]
```

arrayTwo:

```
[
    "#1c2130",
    "#028f76",
    "#b3e099",
    "#ffeaad",
    "#d14334"
]
```

my desired new array would be:

```
[
    "#f8edd1",
    "#028f76",
    "#b3e099",
    "#9d9d93",
    "#d14334"
]
```

So the `selected` color(s), would still be in the same index/position in the array. The desired array can be a completely new array or updated arrayOne or Two. The main issue I ran into was mapping it when there was more than 1 object with the `selected: true`.

This was my first stab at it:

```
  const selectedColors = arrayOne.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj.selected === true
  })
  if (selectedColors) {
    const lockedIndex = arrayOne.findIndex((obj) => {
      if (obj.color === selectedColors[0].color) {
        return true
      }
    })
    const newColors = arrayTwo.splice(lockedIndex, 1, selectedColors[0].color)
    console.log(newColors)
  }
```

Also note that arrayOne is actually a React useState, but i'm not looking to update the useState, I'm doing something else with the `newColors` - but if it's easier to create a seperate useState to execute what i'm trying to do, that's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably just use `.map` function on `arrayTwo` and use second argument which is an index. Then just return original element if corresponding element was not selected or the value of that element:

```
arrayTwo.map((element, index) => arrayOne[index].selected ? arrayOne[index].color : element)
```

```js
const arrayOne = [
    {
        "color": "#f8edd1",
        "selected": true
    },
    {
        "color": "#d88a8a",
        "selected": false
    },
    {
        "color": "#474843",
        "selected": false
    },
    {
        "color": "#9d9d93",
        "selected": true
    },
    {
        "color": "#c5cfc6",
        "selected": false
    }
];

const arrayTwo = [
    "#1c2130",
    "#028f76",
    "#b3e099",
    "#ffeaad",
    "#d14334"
]

const result = arrayTwo.map((element, index) => arrayOne[index].selected ? arrayOne[index].color : element);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly!! Question, will this still work if the 2 arrays do not have the same number of indexes?

Comment: It will work as long as arrayTwo has same or a greater number of elements in it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you'll need arrayOne and arrayTwo later on so I created a third one like so :

```
const arrayThree = [];
arrayOne.forEach(function(element, index) {
  arrayThree.push(element.selected ? element.color : arrayTwo[index]);
});
```

Here, we iterate on arrayOne with a forEach loop. We use two parameters to get corresponding values:

*element* = the object at a given index in arrayOne

Be aware that forEach loop is asynchronous code. So, if you need arrayThree the line right after the forEach loop and you have to iterate a list of hundreds of element, you may get an empty array. In that case, you can try to use a regular loop :

```
const arraythree = [];
for(const [index, element] of arrayOne.entries()) {
  arrayThree.push(element.selected ? element.color : arrayTwo[index]);
}
```

If you need more information, let me know.

```js
const arrayOne = [
    {
        "color": "#f8edd1",
        "selected": true
    },
    {
        "color": "#d88a8a",
        "selected": false
    },
    {
        "color": "#474843",
        "selected": false
    },
    {
        "color": "#9d9d93",
        "selected": true
    },
    {
        "color": "#c5cfc6",
        "selected": false
    }
];

const arrayTwo = [
    "#1c2130",
    "#028f76",
    "#b3e099",
    "#ffeaad",
    "#d14334"
];

const arrayThree = [];
arrayOne.forEach(function(element, index) {
  arrayThree.push(element.selected ? element.color : arrayTwo[index]);
});

console.log('result : ', arrayThree)
```